# May I know what's wrong in the code since it keep call the function again and again and cause infinite loop

Tags: swift, sdk

I had use the PSPDKIT in it and I try to call this function to display my pdf file, but it keeps looping my file.

```
class PDFViewController: PSPDFViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate = self
        processorExample()
        uploadfile()
    }

    func uploadfile()
    {
        let fileURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("Exhibit-A-SAMPLE-CONTRACT.pdf")
        let writableURL = copyFileURLToDocumentFolder(fileURL)
        let document = PSPDFDocument(url: fileURL)
        let configuration = PSPDFConfiguration { builder in
            builder.thumbnailBarMode = .scrollable
        }

        let pdfController = PDFViewController(document: document, configuration: configuration)
        present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: pdfController), animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
```

I expect that it will only call the function one time but it keeps calling the function.

Comment: Why are you creating and presenting another `PDFViewController` from inside `PDFViewController`?

Comment: Because I wish to present the pdf file out, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your first `PDFViewController` loads
2. Its `viewDidLoad()` function is called
3. `viewDidLoad()` calls `uploadFile()`
4. `uploadFile()` calls `present(_:animated:completion:)` with your second `PDFViewController`.
5. When the second `PDFViewController` is presented, *it calls **its** `viewDidLoad()` method*.
6. That `viewDidLoad()` method calls `uploadFile()`
7. ...